# Nodejs POST gets 400 from python instance

Tags: python, json, node.js, http

I have the following NODEjs POST function that sends a request to a localhost port running a python script:

```
function httpPost(callback, host, path, headers, body, port){

    if(port == undefined){
        port = 80;
    }

    if(headers == undefined){
        var headers = {};
    }

    if(headers['Content-Type'] == undefined)
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

    var post_options = {
          host: host,
          path: path,
          port: port,
          method: 'POST',
          headers: headers
    };

    if(headers['Content-Type'] == "application/json"){
        post_options["json"] = true;
    }

    //either 'querystring' or 'JSON' do not work:
    var post_data = JSON.stringify(body);
    //var post_data = querystring.stringify(body);

     var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {

          res.setEncoding('utf8');

          res.on('data', function (chunk) {
              console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
          });

      });

      // post the data
      post_req.write(post_data);
      post_req.end();

}
```

This is the route in the python script (not coded by me):

```
@app.route('/search', methods = ['POST'])
def search():
    if request.headers['Content-Type'] != 'application/json':
        return "Requests must be in JSON format. Please make sure the header is 'application/json' and the JSON is valid."

    client_json = json.dumps(request.json)
    client_data = json.loads(client_json)
    code = doSearch(client_data['image_url'])

    return parseResults(code)
```

And this is my request using httpPost:

```
    var headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    var body = {
        "parameter":parameter
    }

    ut.httpPost(function(response){

        callback(response);

    },host_endpoint,"/search",headers,body,5000);
```

**1. The request is received in the python process**

**2. If I remove the json content type I get the notice "body must be in JSON", so that is not the problem.**

**3. This regular request hands out a 400 response. No further information:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

And in the python instance:

```
 Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2017 16:09:25] "POST /search HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

So, what exactly I'm I missing here?
Tyvm

### Edit

Again, **the python scripts works completely by cURL requests**. It just fails using node. Here is the `doSearch` python function:

```
def doSearch(url):

    returned_code = StringIO()
    full_url = SEARCH_URL + url

    if app.debug:
        print 'POST: ' + url

    conn = pycurl.Curl()
    conn.setopt(conn.URL, str(full_url))
    conn.setopt(conn.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
    conn.setopt(conn.USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11')
    conn.setopt(conn.WRITEFUNCTION, returned_code.write)
    conn.perform()
    conn.close()
    return returned_code.getvalue()
```

One last time, **the python script FULLY WORKS** if I use the terminal to POST to localhost:5000 (where the python instance is running). It only fails when the request comes from the node.js function.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `parseResults` please? That's probably causing the 400 response.

Comment: @supersam654 not at all, I don't think so... This is code for a HTML scraper so literally parseResults is simply using beautifulsoup to breakdown the html page received. It works with terminal cURL requests. However I'm posting the `doSearch` because the problem might be there indeed, take a look at the edit please

Comment: you can you netcat to listen for incoming request and compare your python and node  requests to see difference command is : `nc -vv -l 80`

Comment: @Anonymous thanks for your input. I listened in port 5000 using netcat and sent a request there from my nodejs instance. It logged like this exactly:

`Connection from [127.0.0.1] port 5000 [tcp/*] accepted (family 2, sport 51742)
POST /search HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

59
{"parameter":"test"}
0

`

Just so that I'm completely clear, the "59" and "0" also appear in the request. Could that be the problem?